# How to format a large variable of text into smaller variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, formatting

I'm using an API to pull data through to my application, and I'm pulling an object and it's property, however the property is just a large wall of text (shown below).  The reason I can't use all the text is well...Because n

Is it possible to format this wall of text into smaller variables or such?

My current code is finding the length from the start of the text to the first fullstop, then creating a variable with that length to grab the first sentence.

```
//what it currently shows//
"Leonard Shelby is tracking down the man who raped and murdered his wife. 
The difficulty of locating his wife's killer, however, is compounded by 
the fact that he suffers from a rare, untreatable form of short-term 
memory loss. Although he can recall details of life before his accident, 
Leonard cannot remember what happened fifteen minutes ago, where he's 
going, or why."

//What I want it to look like
"Leonard Shelby is tracking down the man who raped and murdered his wife.

The difficulty of locating his wife's killer, however, is compounded by 
the fact that he suffers from a rare, untreatable form of short-term 
memory loss.

Although he can recall details of life before his accident, 
Leonard cannot remember what happened fifteen minutes ago, where he's 
going, or why."


//my code//
var fullTvShowOverview = tvShow.overview;
var tvShowOverView = document.getElementById("tvshow-description");

var trimmedTvShowLength = fullTvShowOverview.indexOf(".");
var trimmedTvShowOverview = fullTvShowOverview.substring(0, 
trimmedTvShowLength,  ".");
trimmedTvShowOverview = trimmedTvShowOverview + ".";
tvShowOverView.textContent = trimmedTvShowOverview;


//my code produces: "Leonard Shelby is tracking down the man who raped and murdered his wife."
```

Comment: what is your question? Your code seems to be doing what you're requesting already.

Comment: How can I get **all** of the text into smaller variables? My code get's the first sentence but how can I get all the other sentences into different variables?

Comment: push each chunk into an array

Answer (score 0):

You will want to split the text string into an array, and then loop the array for your processing later. Here's a minimal example that is splitting on just `.`

```js
let textStr ="This. is some. example. text.";

let results = textStr.split(". ");

console.log( results[1] )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place in an array and just use the indices to access each sentence

```js
var fullTvShowOverview = "Leonard Shelby is tracking down the man who raped and murdered his wife.The difficulty of locating his wife's killer, however, is compounded by the fact that he suffers from a rare, untreatable form of short-term memory loss.Although he can recall details of life before his accident,Leonard cannot remember what happened fifteen minutes ago, where he's going, or why.";
var tvShowOverView = document.getElementById("tvshow-description");

var arraySplitByPeriod = fullTvShowOverview.split(".")

tvShowOverView.textContent = arraySplitByPeriod[0];
```

```html
<div id="tvshow-description">

<div>
```